# why there are two containers corresponding to a k8s pod?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Whenever i do a "docker ps -a", i see two containers corresponding to pod, here the pod has only container. Typically, the two containers listed under "docker ps" has the following prefixes:-
**k8s_POD_kubernetes-<POD_NAME> and k8s_kubernetes-<POD_NAME>**

Can someone help me understand why we see two entries in "docker ps" ?

Comment: you are running kubernetes on GKE, EKS, minikube ? both containers are running status ? it could be possible one from another deployment or stopped condition exited.

Comment: I think i found the answer. These are "pause" containers which get created for each pod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_POD_` one is the only one with the Pod's IP address, the others are every *workload* container from the PodSpec's `container:` and `initContainer:` arrays, since one of the contracts of Kubernetes is that [all containers in a Pod share the same network identity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#workload-resources-for-managing-pods)

The nitty gritty of that involves the different namespaces in the Linux kernel that make "containers" operate, with cgroups for cpu, memory, process ids, and network stack. Just like `nsenter` allows the host to temporarily switch its cgroup into a container's cgroup, so does the container runtime mechanism have the "sibling" containers in a Pod switch into the allocated networking cgroup of that "sandbox" container, otherwise traffic sent from `container[0]` and `container[1]` would appear as different hosts, violating that network identity promise

That's also why a container within a Pod can restart without the Pod losing its IP address and `.metadata.name` because only the workload containers are restarted, the `_POD_` version remains running. It's also why you'll always see [`k8s.gcr.io/pause` images](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/blob/v0.12.0/images/base/files/etc/containerd/config.toml#L30) in your Node's `docker images` list, because that container is designed to "do nothing" except exist